# AAA- Unit testing file IO - logging

Tags: c#, unit-testing, file-io, arrange-act-assert

I am writing a custom logger for a program. I am using NLog as much as possible. I am looking to verify functionality and have written some unit tests using the AAA pattern.

However this causes the problem with Assert.... How can I/Whats the best method for Asserting a file write happened... and it wrote out correctly.

I mean I can do a file.read to get the last line, and assert it is equal to the param written out... I just dont know if that defeats the AAA purpose....

Comment: Do you use NLog loggers to implement your custom logger? Are you writing to file yourself or do you use NLog to do that?

Answer (score 1):

One Unit Test should not influence the outcome of another unit test.

AND

unit tests may run in parallel

So: you should not log from several tests to the same file.

- Try to use a private logger/logfile in each test
- Clear the logfile in the Arrange phase
- Check contents of complete file, not just the last line

Comment: I guess I worded that poorly, Only one line is written in each test, as I didnt want to run write tests in parallel, the file is cleared after each time, I just wasnt sure the best method to test the contents outside of a read the file and compare,

Comment: Well, most Unit-Test frameworks will run your tests in parallel, and you should design your tests in a way that this is possible.